# Hide radial tick labels matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a polar plot with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
def power(angle, l, lam):
    return 1/(lam) * ((np.cos(np.pi*l*np.cos(angle)/lam) - np.cos(np.pi*l/lam))/np.sin(angle))**2
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
theta = np.linspace(0.001, 2*np.pi, 100)
P1 = power(theta, 1, 5)
ax.plot(theta, P1, color='r', linewidth=3)
plt.savefig('1.png')
```

and I get this plot:

[image]

I would like to change 2 things. The first and more important one is to hide the radial tick labels (I just want to show the general form of the plot).

If possible, how can I choose the vertical axis to correspond to 0°?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `set_yticklabels()` to remove the radial ticks and `set_theta_zero_location()` to change the zero location:

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, P1, color='r', linewidth=3)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
plt.show()
```

You might also want to change the direction of the azimuthal axis:

```
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the theta zero position with `ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')`.

To modify the r tick labels, you could do something like

```
for r_label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    r_label.set_text('')
```

If you want to remove them entirely, do `ax.set_yticklabels([])`.

More methods can be found in [the PolarAxes documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/devel/add_new_projection.html?highlight=polaraxes#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes).