# why my bar chart on polar axis doesn't start drawing from the center of the circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw polar bar chart with the radial axis starting at r=0.9 at the center, using matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar, here is the example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_bar.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-bar-py
I made some changes to the example to fit my data, here is my code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 15
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
r = np.array(
    [0.9928, 0.9854, 0.9829, 0.9794, 0.9727, 0.9698, 0.9657, 0.9641, 0.9651, 0.9482, 0.9557, 0.9404, 0.9360, 0.9270,
     0.9253])
width = np.array([0.4] * N)
label = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.set_rlim(0.9, 1)
ax.set_rticks(np.arange(0.94, 1, 0.02))
ax.set_thetagrids(theta * 180 / np.pi)
ax.set_rlabel_position(-15)

ax.bar(x=theta, height=r, width=width, bottom=0.0, alpha=0.5, tick_label=label)

plt.show()
```

But I found that the center of the circle is very neat, it seems that the bar doesn't start from r=0.9 the the center of the circle.

The plot looks like this:

[image]

The arrow is the center of the circle.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: the plot is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Py8d.png, the arrow is the center of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start your plot at r=0.9. To this end, also let your bars start at r=0.9 instead of r=0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 15
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
r = np.array(
    [0.9928, 0.9854, 0.9829, 0.9794, 0.9727, 0.9698, 0.9657, 0.9641, 0.9651, 0.9482, 0.9557, 0.9404, 0.9360, 0.9270,
     0.9253])
width = np.array([0.4] * N)
label = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.set_rlim(0.9, 1)
ax.set_rticks(np.arange(0.94, 1, 0.02))
ax.set_thetagrids(theta * 180 / np.pi)
ax.set_rlabel_position(-15)

ax.bar(x=theta, height=r-.9, width=width, bottom=0.9, alpha=0.5, tick_label=label)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! your answer perfectly solve my problem! Thank you! In addition, do you know how to hide rlabel? PolarAxes class only have set_rlabel_position, so I am confused about how to configure rlabel, including hide or change the text of rlabel. This is my another problem, but I don't want to repeat my question again, so I hope you can help me too. Thanks again!

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852861/hide-radial-tick-labels-matplotlib