# How to plot the numerical solution of an ODE in a polar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm solving numerically an ODE and I would like to plot its solution in a polar plot. However, when I run my code it doesn't yield any plot. How could a perform this task? Here is my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

def model1(y,t):
    dydt = -np.sqrt((y**4)*(1-1.2/(-3+2*y)-(27*(1-2/y)*(1-1.2/(-3+2*y)))/(y**2)))/(3.*np.sqrt(3))
    return dydt

def model2(y,t):
    dydt = np.sqrt((y**4)*(1-1.2/(-3+2*y)-(27*(1-2/y)*(1-1.2/(-3+2*y)))/(y**2)))/(3.*np.sqrt(3))
    return dydt
# initial condition
y01 = 3-.0001
y02 = 2.1+0.0001
# time points
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)

# solve ODE
yd = odeint(model1,y01,t)
yc = odeint(model2,y02,t)

# plot results
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(fig_sizes,fig_sizes)) 
ax.plot(t, yd)
#plt.plot(t,yd)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.savefig('teste.png', dpi = 300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: I have a notebook on how to plot in polar coordinates that you will find useful.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YGPQcgu3L74pPV_9O8LsyHmyzXgw8hjC
Try adding plt.show()

Comment: 1) remove `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(fig_sizes,fig_sizes)) `

Comment: Even with what I indicate there will be a problem since the range of data on the radial axis is between 2.98 and 2.99 which is too small to be observed.

Comment: @eyllanesc Even if I increase the domain horizon in the computation it still doesn't show me anything... Is there any other way to plot this solution in a polar plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you tried to insert the figure after already creating an axis plot. Specifically,

```
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(fig_sizes,fig_sizes))
```

So, we can remove the second subplot because a polar plot has no attribute figsize.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

def model1(y,t):
    dydt = -np.sqrt((y**4)*(1-1.2/(-3+2*y)-(27*(1-2/y)*(1- 
            1.2/(-3+2*y)))/(y**2)))/(3.*np.sqrt(3))
    return dydt

def model2(y,t):
    dydt = np.sqrt((y**4)*(1-1.2/(-3+2*y)-(27*(1-2/y)*(1-1.2/(-3+2*y)))/(y**2)))/(3.*np.sqrt(3))
    return dydt

# initial condition
y01 = 3-.0001
y02 = 2.1+0.0001
# time points
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)

# solve ODE
yd = odeint(model1,y01,t)
yc = odeint(model2,y02,t)

# plot results
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(t, yd)
ax.plot(t, yc)
# plt.savefig('teste.png', dpi = 300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

*EDIT* I added the second solution so that the plot is noticeable.
[image: Solutions]

Comment: Even I make these changes no plot is generated in my python yet.

Comment: This code plots the data but there is not enough data. This can be viewed if you try `ax.plot(t,t)`. This answers your questions given the data.

Comment: Notice the notebook I created where I plot `ax.plot(t,t)`. The data you gave is negligible. 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JfmLOoC8uhVCLZqVc6H6lCoOIOFKu-Wv

Answer (score 2):

If you make the changes that Bryce suggested, the plot is there, it is just on the very  border of the polar plot so makes it hard to see. You need to change the radius limits (y limits) like:

```
plt.ylim(0, 5)
```

When I did that (and plotted both models) I got the following plot:

[image]

Comment: I'm using spyder to run Python and I am getting the following error message "RuntimeError: dvipng was not able to process the following string:
b'0\\xb0' "

Comment: very nice. This is a great suggestion.

Comment: @BryceWayne One last question, how can I hide the degrees from the plot?

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852861/hide-radial-tick-labels-matplotlib

Comment: So, given the previous link, you can try `ax.set_xticklabels([])` to eliminate the degrees from the plot